# How can I make two divs stack whilst still having my text wrap without media queries

Tags: html, css, video, mobile, responsive

I have managed to make a video responsive for my page and also make the text wrap around the video however I can't get this to work together.

Ideally I would like this:

Desktop version: 
[image: Desktop version]

To become this:
Mobile version

[image: Mobile version]

This is the best I have come up with so far is the content stacks but the text doesn't wrap OR the text wraps but it doesn't stack. How can I do both?

It all needs to be inline and HTML/CSS only as it goes into my POS system which can't handle much.

```html
<div style="max-width:1000px; width:100%;font-size:0px;">
<!--VIDEO-->
<div style="float:right;width:100%; max-width:450px; display:inline:block;">
<div style="width:100%;position:relative; padding-bottom:56.25%; height:0px;">
<iframe style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" height="441" width="480" src="[VIDEO SOURCE]" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!--END VIDEO-->

<p style="font-size:20px; width:100%; max-width:550px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">TEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE  HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You wrote `display:inline:block;` instead of `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @PascalGoldbach  thanks for spotting that - long day! >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change your code little bit but I am not sure this will helps you or not. Please check it once. :)

```html
<div style="max-width:1000px; width:100%;font-size:0px;">
<!--VIDEO-->
<div style="float:right;width:100%; max-width:450px;">
<div style="width:100%;position:relative; padding-bottom:56.25%; height:0px;">
<iframe style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" height="441" width="480" src="[VIDEO SOURCE]" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!--END VIDEO-->

<p style="font-size:20px;">TEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE  HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERETEXT HERE
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS!! I Can't believe it was that simple - That works great as it doesn't have to be fluid but it's the only way I knew how to make it responsive without media queries. It only needs to be two widths so at that width it's fantastic thanks so much!